# Cleaning misspelled names using stri_replace_all_regex

Tags: r

I have a list with a few names, some of which have incorrect spelling.

```
fruits <- c("apple", "two pears", "three bananas", "appl3")
```

I would like to use the `stri_replace_all_regex` method under the `stringi` package to search for any string beginning with 'a' and replacing it with the string 'apple'.

However, I think my use of regular expressions does not capture what I am trying to achieve.

Where I am stuck:

```
stri_replace_all_regex(fruits,"^a","apple")
[1] "applepple"     "two pears"     "three bananas" "appleppl3"

stri_replace_all_regex(fruits,"^a(pple)?$","apple")
[1] "apple"         "two pears"     "three bananas" "appl3"
```

Comment: What should happen for "two appl3s" for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks for strings starting with an 'a' and then removes that 'a' and adds the string 'apple' instead so **a**pple becomes **apple**pple.

What you want is to select the entire string that starts with a and then substitute it with the new string 'apple':

```
stri_replace_all_regex(fruits, "^a.*", "apple")
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can work it out using `base` with `sub` or `gsub`

```
fruits <- c("apple", "two pears", "three bananas", "appl3")
gsub("^a.*", "apple", fruits)

"apple"         "two pears"     "three bananas" "apple"
```

Comment: Thank you, you are correct that for my example both `gsub()` and `stri_replace_all_regex` accomplish the same thing.